# Mixing convergence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, mixing

Given a process $X_n \xrightarrow{d} X$ on some probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$. If for every $B \in \mathcal{A}$ it holds, that
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} P(X_n\in A,B)=P(X\in A)P(B)
$$
and any set $A$ of continuity of the distribution function of $X$, we say the convergence is renyi-mixing in the classical discrete time sense. 
This is shown to be equivalent to: Fix $m$ and for $B\in \sigma(X_{1},\ldots,X_{m})$ with $P(B)>0$ then
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} P(X_n\in A|B)=P(X\in A)
$$

Now lets say we have a continuous time proces $X_t$ with $X_t\xrightarrow{d}X$. If we want the convergence to be renyi-mixing, is it sufficient to show, that for any countable grid $(t_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ with $t_{i}\rightarrow \infty$ as $i\rightarrow \infty$
$$
\lim_{i\rightarrow \infty}P(X_{t_i}\in A,B)=P(X\in A)P(B)
$$
holds?

Best regards

Comment: It appears to me that it is only an extension of a definition in a continuous time context, if the theorems that you can deduct in the discrete time context are true in the continuous time context this should be claimed as OK, but I don't have any reference on this subject neither in discrete nor in continuous time.Maybe this has been already studied (you might have a look here though : http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304414985900444). Best regards

Comment: @TheBridge  Thanks. Yeah i want to extend it to continuous time, so the mixing results hold for $X_t$ with $n$ integer replaced by $t$.  But it should be legit, that $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}P(X_t\in A,B)=P(X\in A)P(B)$ follows from $\lim_{i\rightarrow \infty}P(X_{t_i}\in A, B)=P(X\in A)P(B)$ in the mixing sense, considering especially processes $X_t$ in the Skorohd-space. Due to the arbitrary fine grid $t_i$, i can controll possible explosions. Right?

Comment: well here are my two cents,  processes that are continuous in probability are Lévy processes. Maybe for those, it is possible to extend the property of Renyi-mixing in a straightforward way ? Best regards

Comment: @TheBridge The extension of Renyi-mixing should be immediate for Levy-Processes according to the continuity in probability. Or do i miss s.th.? Best regards and thanks for your help

Comment: You tell me ;-) Best regards.

Comment: @TheBridge A specific proof is more complicated than i thought. Due to the continuity in probability for each $t$ there exists for each sequence $t_i\rightarrow t$ we have $\lim_{i\rightarrow \infty} P(|X_{t_i}-X_t|\geq \epsilon)=0$ Like we take a grid of $\mathbb{Q}_{+}$-times in $\mathbb{R}_{+}$. Since it holds in the limit for $\mathbb{Q}_{+}$ times it should hold for $t$ also. However i don't know if one can adept it to the limit case, where $t\rightarrow \infty$. Do you have an approach idea. Like: With what it is best to start?

Comment: Let $t_{n}$ a dense countable grid of the time interval. Intuitively it just says, that $B$ and the events $X_{t_n}$ grow furhter away, such that they are independent in the limit. So inuitivley it would hold for $X_t$. But my attempts are very blurry. Best regards